# "Faking" Session variable(HttpSessionstateBase) of the controller in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, microsoft-fakes

I am presently working on unit testing using Microsoft Fakes and testing a controller which uses some session variables.
         Since no session is being initiated during unit test creation whenever I'm running unit test I'm stuck with a NullReferenceException.I have seen many question and answers doing it using Moqs but I want it in Microsoft Fakes.
        I know I need to use shims to fake session  variable ,since I'm not having a clear idea about how exactly session is being created I'm stuck there.
        Please explain me how exactly a session is created so that I can fake it,also if possible please let me know how to write it in microsoft fakes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can this as example :

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public bool SomeMethod()
    {
        var session = HttpContext.Current.Session;
        if (session["someSessionData"].ToString() == "OK")
            return true;
        return false;               
    }
}

[TestMethod]
public void SomeTestMethod()
{
    using (ShimsContext.Create())
    {
        var instanceToTest = new SomeClass();

        var session = new System.Web.SessionState.Fakes.ShimHttpSessionState();
        session.ItemGetString = (key) => { if (key == "someSessionData") return "OK"; return null; };

        var context = new System.Web.Fakes.ShimHttpContext();
        System.Web.Fakes.ShimHttpContext.CurrentGet = () => { return context; };
        System.Web.Fakes.ShimHttpContext.AllInstances.SessionGet =
            (o) =>
            {
                return session;
            };

        var result = instanceToTest.SomeMethod();
        Assert.IsTrue(result);
    }
}
```

Please see http://blog.christopheargento.net/2013/02/02/testing-untestable-code-thanks-to-ms-fakes/ for more details. 
Have a nice day.

Comment: I tried the same thing but it didnt work i was still getting the null reference exception .Since the session variable is HttpSessionStateBase and it is no where mocked in this example probably it didnt work.But please explain me why you are mokcing it in tht way

Comment: Did you tried to add fakes assembly on System.Web( http://puu.sh/joNw3/49e7bff6ab.png)?